# Ubuntu Bash's Colors - How to disable colors & make it monochrome color instead?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I'm using Win10 with Ubuntu Linux installed with Bash.

I'm having trouble reading BASH multiple colors and want to switch it to monochrome color (2 colors) for easier reading.

I tried Google search and can't find the Ubuntu Bash command line for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use two colors, we can add three lines to `~/.bashrc` to achieve that.
We add three lines at the end of `~/.bashrc`, like this:

```
$vi ~/.bashrc
rt LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "`dircolors`"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

After add it completed, we exit this bash to flush it, then login this bash, here is my result:
[image]

Also, if you want to set other colors, we can follow this [link](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html) to do it.

Here a similar case about you, please refer to [it](https://web.archive.org/web/20140807232939/http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/11/04/changing-the-directory-color-in-the-bash-shell/).

---

**Update:**

We can use CMD to open ubuntu bash, like this:

[image]

Comment: Well, I mean the whole thing beside the `ls command` itself.  Like the Azure CLI's color output too.

Comment: @fletchsod Are you looking for this? we can use windows CMD command line tool to open this bash, I will update my answer, please check it.

Comment: @fletchsod Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: We never got that far now. It crashed after tweaking the file, in trying to make it work and now bash command no longer work correctly. We haven't decided the next step cuz it take up too much of our time at work.